# Can't set up UrlRewrite to redirect HTTP to HTTPS and require client certificate

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, client-certificates

I have an IIS site in which:
- I need to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
- I need to require client certificates

The first part works fine, with a simple rule which redirects from HTTP to HTTPS.

However, if I modify the SSL settings of the site to require SSL and client certificate, if I try to access the site using http, instead of getting a redirection, I get an error.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to setup 2 different sites in IIS, for the same domain:

- one bound only to HTTP, usually in port 80
- another one bound to HTTPS, usually in port 443, with its certificate

The first site is simply an empty site that only has a `web.config` file that redirects all request to https. This is its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard"
      stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
     </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```